# Confused about how to pass variables to an include containing a Class containing a Protected Function

Tags: php

I have got a page in which a UserID variable is declared. Eg...

```
$userid = 1;
```

Like any other variable, this is easily called elsewhere on the page.

However, the page also contains an include for a file containing a class, containing a protected function. Eg.

```
include('../dir/dir/whatever.php');
```

**Contents of whatever.php:**

```
class Whatever
{
    protected function whatever()
    {
        echo $userid;
    }
}
```

However, the function is unable to get the value of $userid.

I'm not very experienced with PHP and I'd like to understand how I can pass the function to the variable? I read about declaring variables as global, but this didn't work and also I heard it's bad practice.

Comment: How about `protected function whatever($userid) { echo $userid; }`? You need to pass it somehow. Other option is creating a class' attribute with setter and getter and access it as `$whateverObj->getUserid()`;

Comment: yah, of course I meant `class' property` not attribute, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid']=$userid;
include('../dir/dir/whatever.php');
```

whatever.php file

```
class Whatever
   {
       protected function whatever()
       {

       echo $_SESSION['userid'];

       }
   }
```

Comment: I think you mean `$_SESSION['userid']` ^^

Comment: Yes sorry bro mobile keyboard auto change this

Comment: No worries, I meant well :)

Comment: That's kinda weird anyway, what's the purpose of using $_SESSION instead of method arguments in the same script?

Comment: @biesior think it depends on how hacky you want to write code. I would choose over parsing an argument, but this would work aswell, not as gentle as parsing an argument though

Comment: In my case this actually does work nicely, albeit the userid is already in the active session, so I can just grab it - no idea why I didn't think of this. So thanks for the sanity check! But good to see the other answer that looks at pushing the variable through properly.

Comment: Of course in general I try to keep the rule: use method's arguments where it is required and sessions if you need sessions. Mixing these approaches just because in some cases they may be *more comfortable* is just wrong design pattern... IMHO ofc...

Answer (score 0):

#### Protected Function

**Only can be used inside the class and child classes. Inherited by child classes.**

If you still want to access that function outside class you can do like this:

```
class Whatever
{
    protected function test($userid)
    {
        return $userid;
    }
}

$userid = "1";

$class = new ReflectionMethod('Whatever', 'test');
$class->setAccessible(true);
$funtion = $class->invoke(new Whatever(), $userid);
echo $funtion;
```

here Whatever is class name and test is function name

But I thing it is bad idea to modify class make it public if you  want access outside class.

in case if you want to learn more about ReflectionMethod please check below link: 
[ReflectionMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)